# grub.cfg is missing, is there a way to recreate it

Tags: centos, grub

I am running CentOS, my gurb.conf file is missing. Can anyone recommend me how I can generate it and not re-create it ?

Thanks !

Comment: I answered what I think your question may be. Still it's unclear what file exactly you are talking about (`gurb.conf` vs `grub.cfg`? where is it missing from?). And what makes "generating" different from "re-creating"? Why does the title want to "recreate" while the question body wants "generate, *not* re-create"? Please respond by improving the question ([edit] it).

Comment: Also if EFI partition is present mount it before attempting any change.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grub-mkconfig` or `grub2-mkconfig` to generate `grub.cfg`. In my Debian I have the former (plus `update-grub`, a script that knows where `grub.cfg` should be). According to [this howto](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Grub2) in CentOS you have the latter.

> Do not attempt to manually edit the boot menu because it is automatically created from files within the `/boot/` directory tree. However you can adjust the `/etc/default/grub` file that defines the general settings and the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file to add specific custom entries.
>
> […]
>
> Changes to the setting is made effective by executing the following command:
>
> ```
> grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
> ```

<sup>Note: you need `sudo` for this.</sup>

> […]
>
> On UEFI-based systems, the command will be `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg`

Comment: Error= impossible to get the canonical path for cow. I run a live session.